# How identifiable is The Wall in The Handmaid's Tale?

Tags: real-location, the-handmaids-tale

This is a somewhat peculiar question, and I recognize that it may end up being closed.  However, it concerns something that has been puzzling me for some years about Margaret Atwood's *The Handmaid's Tale*.  (Atwood's well-known feelings about SF notwithstanding, this novel is clearly science fiction.)

Early in the book, there is the first description of The Wall:

> The Wall is hundreds of years old too; or over a hundred, at least. Like the sidewalks, it's red brick, and must once have been plain but handsome. Now the gates have sentries and there are ugly new floodlights mounted on metal posts above it, and barbed wire along the bottom and broken glass set in concrete along the top.

Aside from the sidewalks being made of the same brick as the wall, there seems to be very little that marks this wall as specifically identifiable.  And yet, from the first time I read this passage, I knew this wall.  Having lived in Cambridge, Massachusetts, I could tell that this was the wall of Harvard Yard, which I walked beside some many times over the years.  Reading on in the novel, it quite clear that I was quite correct in my identification of the wall.

What I a wondering is whether this was a particularly lucky flash of insight on my part, or whether there was something in the text that pointed to Harvard Square as the location of the book.  Is there something, early in *The Handmaid's Tale*, that points specifically to its geographic setting?

Comment: There are [multiple](http://www.nytimes.com/1986/02/09/books/no-headline-423986.html?pagewanted=2) out-of-universe [interviews](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/03/10/books/review/margaret-atwood-handmaids-tale-age-of-trump.html) that explicitly confirm that the story is set in Cambridge, Mass

Comment: Oh, there's no doubt about where the book is set.  By the *end* of the book, it's very obvious if you know the area.  But I was wondering about earlier in the story

Comment: Interesting question. It looks to be on-topic here, but you might want to ask on [Literature.SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) too. There's overlap, but I imagine that some of the folks there might read a novel like The Handmaid's Tale somewhat differently than most SFF buffs.

Comment: If you do ask the question on Literature, just be sure to word the question differently to fit that community. That way you're not "cross-posting", which is discouraged on SE.

Comment: Aside from the location of the particular narrative we read, the implied setting covers a considerable fraction of the US, and we can conclusively assume that every large community has it public place of punishment. So while our narrator's "The Wall" is in erstwhile Cambridge, there will be others.

Comment: *Like the sidewalks, it’s red brick.* I'm pretty sure fired clay brick sidewalks are a New England thing [citation needed]. There's your first clue. Harvard was built before we started importing portland, and we were never big on cobblestones or setts.

Comment: ... and once we know we're in NE, and someone mentions 'university' (page 26), I'll give you three guess where we are. 99% of the American population would guess right on the first try of, *just name a university*... "Harvard."

Comment: @Jolenealaska But please leave this question here as well. The idea of Atwood's precious _speculative fiction_ becoming an HNQ on SciFi and Fantasy makes me smile.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Lots of the things mentioned *point* to it being Harvard Square. E.g., "we used to be able to walk  freely  there,  when  it
was a university."

However the word *Harvard* is absent the entire book, and *Cambridge* (*England*) only appears in the notes at the end (assuming this is a full transcript: [www.novelas.rodriguezalvarez.com](http://www.novelas.rodriguezalvarez.com/pdfs/Atwood,%20M.%20%27%27The%20Handmaid%27s%20Tale%27%27-Xx-En-Sp-Xx.pdf)).

[*Memorial Hall*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorial_Hall_(Harvard_University)) is mentioned.

> "large  old  building  on  it;
>   ornate  late  Victorian,  with
>   stained  glass.  It  used  to  be
>   called    Memorial    Hall"
>
> (page 238 of 375)

*Maine* is mentioned twice.

> “I  almost  made  it  out.
>   They  got  me  up  as  far  as
>   Salem, then in a truck full
>   of  chickens  to  Maine."
>
> (page 303 of 375)

---

> This item—I hesitate to
>   use  the  word 
>   document
>   —
>   was uncurl hod on the site
>   of what was once the city
>   of Bangor, in what, at the
>   time prior to the inception
>   of  the  Gileadean  regime,
>   would have been the state
>   of  Maine.
>
> (page 357 of 375)

Is there *early* PROOF? No. Not unless describing the white staircase of the library counts. I'm assuming it looks exactly like this:

> The  Library  is  like  a
>   temple.  There’s  a  long
>   flight   of   white   steps,
>   leading  to  the  rank  of
>   doors.     Then,     inside,
>   another  white  staircase
>   going up. To either side of
>   it,  on  the  wall,  there  are
>   angels. Also there are men
>   fighting, or about to fight,
>   looking  clean  and  noble,
>   not dirty and bloodstained
>   and  smelly  the  way  they must have looked. Victory
>   is on one side of the inner
>   doorway, leading them on,
>   and  Death  is  on  the  other.
>   It’s  a  mural  in  honor  of
>   some war or other. The men
>   on  the  side  of  Death  are
>   still alive. They’re going to
>   heaven. Death is a beauti-
>   ful woman, with wings and
>   one  breast  almost  bare;  or
>   is that Victory? I can’t re-
>   member.
>
> (page 195 of 375)

If so, you're not lucky; [just like the author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Handmaid%27s_Tale#Setting) you've been there, and that's cheating.