# Where does The Handmaid's Tale take place?

Tags: the-handmaids-tale

Is which town or region does the Handsmaid's Tale take place?

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/163382/2865

Comment: I'd be inclined to say this should be closed as a dup to the linked question, under the logic that the linked question fully answers this question.  (It was asking about if people could identify the location as easily as the OP, but contains within it the location.)